# Slides won't import my keynote file

Tags: google-slides, import

I was sent a keynote file from a colleague, to use as a template for another presentation.  It's a very simple deck, just a visual template really for layout.  Simple black text on white.  Super no-frills.

When I try to import it into Google Slides, I'm told that the filetype is not supported, and it just bails.  I was under the distinct impression that slides could import .key files.  I don't have/use keynote but I am on a mac so I *could* get it if I need to, but I hate to install a whole additional application when all I need is to import one file, one time.

So why does this fail and what options do I have to get it to import?

Comment: Apple's Keynote is a presentation program (like Microsoft's PowerPoint), not a spreadsheet program. Google Sheets is a spreadsheet program. If you are trying to import a Keynote file, you'd want to be importing to Google Slides, not Spreadsheet.

Comment: OMG I meant Google SLIDES!  I use sheets so much I typed it on autopilot!  Will correct... lol

Comment: It's hard to say without access to that file. But you can try converting it to a PowerPoint file first (try **zamzar.com**) and seeing if you can upload the .pptx file to Slides. If the file won't convert to .pptx, then something else may be going on with the file.

Comment: Yeah I tried opening it in PPT but it doesn't take Keynote files at all.  At this point I could just installed Keynote I just really didn't expect this to be such a problem.

Comment: I didn't mean trying to open it in PPT. I meant *converting* it to .pptx using zamzar.com, and then trying to upload the converted file to Slides. PowerPoint would not be able to directly open a .pages file.

Comment: Yeah I realize that, I don't want to use an external service for this, frankly I just asked my colleague to import it into Slides for me and send me the link.

Comment: Sounds like you're all set then. However, zamzar.com is a free online tool that converts many file types quickly (about 30 seconds), and I use it all the time when people send me files in formats of programs I don't own. So tuck it away. (BTW, I am not an affiliate of zamzar, just a regular user like anyone else who appreciates their service.)